# How to obtain standard error of parameters in maximum likelihood when reparametrized/transformed?

Tags: probability, estimation, maximum-likelihood, standard-error, hessian

Sometimes parameters in the maximum likelihood estimation process are reparametrized for numerical convenience. As an example if I'm fitting maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) to a data that is normally distributed, we have two parameters that is mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma^2$ to be estimated using numerical optimization.

One of the constraints is $\sigma^2$ should be $>0$, otherwise the numerical optimizer will throw an error. One way to get around this issue is to use a constrained optimizer such as "L-BFGS-B". An alternative better option is to reparametrize $\sigma^2$ to be $exp(\sigma^2)$ so the value of $\sigma^2$ is unbounded but still be positive always.

Here is a reproducible example in `R`:

```r
## Generate random number with mean 3 and sd = 0.2
y <- rnorm(100,3,0.2)

## Write Log Likelihood

logl <- function(x){
  mu  <- x[1]
  sig <- x[2]
  #reparmeterize sig since should be  >0
  sd <- exp(sig)
  
  -sum(dnorm(y,mu,sd,log = T))
  
}

#Maximize Log Likelihood

oplik <- optim(par = c(2,0.7),logl,hessian = T)

## get the parameters
mu <- oplik$par[1]
## 2.998762
sd <- oplik$par[2]
exp(sd)
## 0.1705749

##How to estimate Standard Error of the estimate
## Hessian Matrix
oplik$hessian
#             [,1]        [,2]
#[1,] 3436.9234330  -0.3990205
#[2,]   -0.3990205 200.0058657

## Invert to obtain variance covariance matrix
vcov_mat <- solve(oplik$hessian)
```

My question is how would one calculate standard error of estimates $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$? Should I exponentiate the hessian matrix [2,2] before I take inverse of it or exponentiate after I take an inverse?

How do I handle covariance of a variable that is transformed, i.e, [1,2] and [2,1] in the example above?

Comment: Often the need for that reparametrization belies a deeper relationship.  Indeed, in your example you ought to write $\sigma^2 = \exp(\tau).$  The value of $\tau$ is interpretable -- it says you should be comparing variances on a multiplicative scale (that is, relative to one another).  Arguably, then, the standard error of $\tau$ is more informative than that of $\sigma^2.$ Indeed, you will find that the sampling distribution of $\hat\tau$ is close to symmetric whereas that of $\hat\sigma^2$ is positively skewed.